# How to put pagination for the newly created thing (after ajax call) in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

My question would seems to be confusing but here I'll explain my need clearly. I have a model named `Post`. I'm using `Ajax` for filtering the `post` via `date`. 
My `index` html looks like this

```
<h1>Posts</h1>
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'posts', :action => 'dateFilter'},remote: 
true )do %>
<%= date_field_tag :start_date %>
<%= date_field_tag :end_date%>
<%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
<div class="row sort_paginate">
<%= render @posts %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @posts ,renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

As you see I'm using a `date` filter in my `post` and I'm using `will-paginate` for pagination and I'm rendering a partial named `post`. I've my `index` and `dateFilter` function in the post controller like this

```
def index
@posts = @posts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 2)
end


def dateFilter
 start_date= params[:start_date].to_date.beginning_of_day
 end_date=params[:end_date].to_date.end_of_day
 @posts=Post.where(created_at: start_date..end_date).paginate(:page => 
 params[:page], :per_page => 2)
 end
```

Finally I've my `dateFilter` `js` as follows

```
$('.sort_paginate').empty().html("<%= j render @posts %>")
```

When I get to index page, I've nice pagination. But when I go for filtering the `post` I'm seeing pagination for the `index` page. I know that I'm using `.html()` which will just replace the `sort_paginate` class and it doesn't affect the `@posts` in `will_paginate` so I'm getting the `index` paginate. But how to do pagination for the filtered posts? I've tried many ways like `ajax-pagination` and I'm not getting what I need.

Hope you guys get my question. Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: `$('.sort_paginate').html("<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@posts, :remote => true)) %>");`

Something of this sorts. Hope it helped.

Comment: I'm getting error like undefined method `paginate'

Comment: You can use this blog as a reference for implementing your desired functionality:
http://codebeerstartups.com/2012/11/pagination-with-ajax-using-will-paginate-in-ruby-on-rails/